# Angular set autorization on HttpClient.get header

Tags: javascript, angular, httpclient

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'git',
  templateUrl: './git.component.html'
})

export class GitComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const headers = {authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzYXNobyIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX1VTRVIiLCJleHAiOjE1MjQwODcyMzJ9.MUv5RgI9LxQyrrCfjfX8HR2-XiQmz4vjLqH7V_0Du7VFLC0WrK_y3FfeNoT2Nj_uguIK2ss7jv-LNiHuCGtz4A'};
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/links/all', headers)
      .subscribe((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```

In the `http.get` how do I set the authorization? I want to use the bearer token saved in `const headers`. That's all. Thanks

Edit: I forgot to mention that i wanted to know how to set it manually here and not with an interceptor, all of the tutorials where with interceptors and so i couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'git',
  templateUrl: './git.component.html'
})

export class GitComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const headers =  'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzYXNobyIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX1VTRVIiLCJleHAiOjE1MjQwODcyMzJ9.MUv5RgI9LxQyrrCfjfX8HR2-XiQmz4vjLqH7V_0Du7VFLC0WrK_y3FfeNoT2Nj_uguIK2ss7jv-LNiHuCGtz4A';
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/links/all', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', headers )
    })
      .subscribe((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: ty for answer, i jsut have a quick fallow up. This returns a the result from the backend, but how can i get http response status like, `200`, `400`, `404`, `403` ?

Comment: To get response status: e.status from response

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
let authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzYXNobyIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX1VTRVIiLCJleHAiOjE1MjQwODcyMzJ9.MUv5RgI9LxQyrrCfjfX8HR2-XiQmz4vjLqH7V_0Du7VFLC0WrK_y3FfeNoT2Nj_uguIK2ss7jv-LNiHuCGtz4A'

 let header: Headers = new Headers;
        header.set('authorization', this.authorization);
        this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/links/all', 
    {headers: header}).subscribe((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Angular http interceptor to append token to every outgoing request:
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Answer (score 0):

You need your headers object *inside* another object `get(....., { headers }`)

The second arg is a general `options` object, for `headers`, request `params`, etc.  See https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

(Contrary to some other answers, you don't need to wrap header in a `HttpHeaders` objects, as the the accepted type is overloaded)